# What is the climb-out angle of a twinjet upon one engine failure scenario?

Tags: aircraft-performance

Take a typical 737-800 or A320 at MTOW how much difference in take off angle does a 1 engine out failure scenario make, compared with a normal 6-8 degree take off angle with full engines.

Comment: Are you asking about a climb angle or gradient, or are you asking about a pitch angle?

Answer (score 3):

The 737 and A320 are certified under Part 25, and they meet the certification requirement in [14 CFR § 25.121](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.121). With the gear retracted and one engine out:

> ... The steady gradient of climb may not be less than 2.4 percent for two-engine airplanes ...

Aircraft Flight Manuals (AFMs) don't typically include the all-engines gradients of climb as noted in [AC 120-91A](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1037135):

> ... It is recognized that many AFMs generally contain **only** the OEI performance for loss of an engine at V$_1$ on takeoff ... [emphasis added]

The OEI (One-Engine Inoperative) scenario is what matters more for obstacle clearance.

#### MTOW alone isn't useful

The performance tables are typically set up for ease of use. *Instead of gradients,* they list the maximum weights that would guarantee the regulatory gradient for the different pressure altitudes and temperatures, which are known as *climb limit weights.*

Consider a 737-800 at MTOW at a hot-and-high airport, it is not given that it can attain the 2.4% with an engine out. The TOW needs to respect the climb limit.

And a 737-800 at MTOW at sea level and cold temperature may exceed the 2.4% with an engine out. In this case, that 737 is not climb limited.

---

As an example, here's the climb limit graph for a 737-800 with flaps 5, note how when it's hotter and/or higher, the climb limit weight is reduced.

> [image]
> Source: 737-800 FPPM; click to view

Comment: Or (IIUC) to look at it a different way, MTOM is determined by the OEI performance chart for the given altitude and weather conditions.